# How to change the title of the JFileChooser dialogbox

Tags: java

I used the JFileChooser.showOpenDialog to open the dialog box. When it is show up, there is "open" on the title of dialog box. I want to change it to be "Add" because my code is for adding a new file. Would someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

There is my dialog box.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JFileChooser's showOpenDialog does not give you the option to change the title of the dialog box (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogTitle(java.lang.String))). You have to use a bit more code for that. The code example in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogTitle(java.lang.String)) comes close:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
chooser.setDialogTitle("Add new file");
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to customize the dialog before the filter.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

fc.setDialogTitle("Title");

fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```